# Derived data type in MPI java

Tags: java, mpi

I am newbie in mpi java, and I want to construct a derived datatype formed by n strings. The idea is send a set of (derived) data to each processor. I have read these doc, https://www.open-mpi.org/papers/mpi-java-spec/mpiJava-spec.pdf, but I am unable to create a valid code.

Could you give me some feedback?

---

@rlegendi I put some code,but I am totally blocked cos' I am not how to proceed.

```
class Data{
   char[] data1;
   char[] data2;

   public Data(String d1, String d2)
   {
        this.data1 = d1.toCharArray();
        this.data2 = d2.toCharArray();
   }
}

class testMPI{
     MPI.Init(argv);
     int myRank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.getRank();
     int nProcs = MPI.COMM_WORLD.getSize();

     Data[] myData = new Data[4]; 
     myData[0] = new Data("d1", "this is a test");
     ....
     myData[3] = new Data("the third data", "this is another test");


     // How to create teh derivated data to send a part of myData[] to several processes???
     if (myRank == 0)
     {
           // calculate offset and chunk
           // send myData[0] and [1] to proc#1 and myData[2] and [3] to proc#2
           for (i=1 ; i < nProcs; i++)
                  MPI.COMM_WORLD.send(myData[offset], chunk, MPI.OBJECT??, i, 1);
     }
     else
           MPI.COMM_WORLD.receive(recv, chunk, MPI.OBJECT??, i, 1);
}
```

So what I don't understand is how to create a derivated MPI datatype to transfer a part of the array to each processor.

Comment: Show us some code. What errors you get?

Comment: You don't need a derived datatype. Send it as a buffer of size `chucnk` like you're doing, with type `MPI.OBJECT.CHAR`, or whatever it's called in JavaMPI.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my original question, what I have not clue is how to send an array slice (of complex datatype, objects, strings, etc...) to each computing element using MPI java.

Thanks.